# sed equivalent syntax for pcre

Tags: php, sed

basically I am using bash shell script `cat new | sed '/1.&nbsp/,/<div/!d' > new2` to extract text starting from `1.&nbsp` and ending at first occurrence of `<div`. And then saving it into a new2 file. How to do the same work in php using pcre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
$matches = array();
if(preg_match('/1\.&nbsp(.*?)<div/', $text, $matches)) {
  echo $matches[1];
}
```

Test:

```
echo 'abc 1.&nbsp;This is a test<div>more stuff<div>and more' | php test.php
;This is a test
```